# How to get audio to play when clicking <li> instead of <option> element - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So basically the goal is to have a list of tracks, and when each one is clicked audio begins to play. At first I used "select" and "option" tags to do this but I want it to be a scrollable list and not a dropdown on iPhone mobile browsers. So I decided to try and use the ul and li tags to do this. Is there a way to get my list items to be clickable so a click event triggers and calls the javascript function "changeTrack"? Feel like I've tried everything to get this to work but Im still clueless.

Check it out here
`a`https://jsfiddle.net/z0usk6rp/9/

The image below is what im trying to avoid by not going with the "select" and "option" tags for my tracklisting[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with select and an attribute `onchange`.

Didn't test on your specific device.

```html
<select id="myoptionst" onchange="console.log(this.value)">
    <option selected  value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love"><a href="#">Shawty In Love</a></option>
    <option value="Soptionm_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</option>
    <option value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love">Shawty In Love</option>
    <option value="Soptionm_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</option>
    <option value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love">Shawty In Love</option>
    <option value="Soptionm_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</option>
    <option value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love">Shawty In Love</option>
    <option value="Soptionm_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</option>
   </select>
```

Or:

```js
myoptionst.onchange = (function(){
 
   console.log(myoptionst.value)
   
 })
```

```html
<select id="myoptionst">
    <option selected  value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love"><a href="#">Shawty In Love</a></option>
    <option value="Soptionm_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</option>
    <option value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love">Shawty In Love</option>
    <option value="Soptionm_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</option>
    <option value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love">Shawty In Love</option>
    <option value="Soptionm_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</option>
    <option value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love">Shawty In Love</option>
    <option value="Soptionm_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</option>
   </select>
```

Following your exact query, the issue should be that a `li` element can't hold a `value` attribute. This is reserved to inputs.
To get a similar behavior, you can use a [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attribute, then you can retrieve it with `dataset`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(e){

  e.setAttribute("onclick", "console.log(this.dataset.value)")

})
```

```html
   <ul id="mylist">
    <li data-value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love"><a href="#">Shawty In Love</a></li>
    <li data-value="Slim_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</li>
    <li data-value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love">Shawty In Love</li>
    <li data-value="Slim_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</li>
    <li data-value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love">Shawty In Love</li>
    <li data-value="Slim_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</li>
    <li data-value="Carti_Shawty_In_Love">Shawty In Love</li>
    <li data-value="Slim_Jimmi_Brink_Truck">Brink Truck</li>
   </ul>
```

Here the script will set an attribute `onclick` to each `li` elements.

The `onclick` will retrieve `data-value` value.

Note: it is a modern ecma6 snippet, take care of compability with old browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your input! But Its still not exactly right. I don't want it to appear as a dropdown menu in Safari on iOS mobile. Thats why I decided to try and make this work with a list rather than the select and option tags. I tried changing the select tag to a "ul" and the option tags to "li" but I can't get the audio to play this way.

Comment: I made an edit. It isn't the only way to do it, mostly make sure that your whole DOM is fully loaded! Good luck!

Comment: Im sorry, but it still isn't working for me. Maybe im doing something wrong? Im still not very adept at javascript so that may be the reason but I put all the files together on Github for you to check out I really appreciate your input! Please look in the "audio" branch https://github.com/johnadegbuji/WeTheSauce.git

Comment: woops actually figured it out, it was an error on my end. Thanks for your help ! @cryptopat